# Mangas/Manhwa where the main character is found in a dump and given bat implants

Tags: story-identification, manga

The protagonist is found in an underground dump, a black pit, by a crazy scientist who takes what is left of him to do some experiments.

If I recall correctly, the scientist puts bat-like implants in him. There was a female protagonist in the lab, another experiment, and she kills the scientist/s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you have 2 stories to identify please ask 2 separate questions, that way each can be answered and accepted.

Comment: I've edited the second question out. You should re-ask it as [a new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

**Dungeon Majesty**

Alt title: Dungeon-ui Juinnim

Summary:
*Juyoon Oh is a typical guy trying to find a full-time job. But one day, he dives into the Han River and puts himself at risk of drowning to save a child that fell in. As he is about to meet an untimely death, a goddess appears before him and gives him a chance at another life... not as a hero or wizard, but as a weak, skill-less “brick larva.” It's the beginning of an atrocious adventure, and the road to become a hero is long!*[image: Le gang]
[image: mc]

Comment: That looks like a lobster arm, not a bat arm

Comment: It is indeed lobster arm, but everything else matches perfectly

Comment: Now, I'm no big city biologist [pulls suspenders], but I'm pretty certain that lobsters aren't a kind of bat

Comment: There is a high possibility that the author got this one confused. I didn't remember what kind of animal parts the mc had as well, and had to look it up.